# How to add title to Lync message with NameCtrl plug-in

Tags: activexobject, lync-2010

I am using ActiveXObject/NameCtrl plug-in to integrate link into my web page (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2013/03/02/integrate-lync-into-your-intranet-sites-using-the-namectrl-plug-in.aspx). Is it possible to add a title to Lync message and subject to email messages when these buttons are clicked from Lync contact card? I have not found a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, not using NameCtrl. You'd need to run a client side app using the Lync SDK/Outlook SDK have control over the title and subjects